# QGIS - tips for visualizing three overlapping layers?

Tags: qgis, layers, transparency-opacity

Does anyone have a suggestion on how best to visualize three overlapping years as seen below?

The yellow/brown part is the base background color of the map.

The grey on the top of the screen represents adjacent countries that are greyed out

Then there are three added layers:

1) green on bottom with no transparency,

2) red on top with 85% transparency, and

3) blue on top with 85% transparency

I think it is difficult for people to visualize the three different layers. Any suggestions on how I could clean this up and make it easier to read? Perhaps on one layer use full transparency with only an outline? Or change the colors so it is easier to see what is overlapping with what? Or use polka dots or cross-hatches? Or do I simply have too many layers and I need to separate them into different maps?

[image]

Comment: Play around with some of your own suggestions; it's rather subjective what works best.  One other thing you might do is union the three layers, and then symbolize off of that layer using the categorized drop down or a newly created symbology field that reflects the different combinations.